# Closing off-topic questions that have an open bounty

Tags: support

I just came across this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260702/jquery-search-website-plugin-to-search-entire-website which has an open bounty, but (for me) is clearly off-topic because it asks us for a plugin recommendation and nothing else.

I tried to close it as such but get this error

[image]

Are questions magically on-topicfied by offering a bounty?